# How can I use string builders to shorten this string?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I have this which is used to enable GC logging:

```
updateJVMArguments("-Xloggc:gc_" + myapp.getFileName() + "-" + getDateTime() +".log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M");
```

As you can see it is pretty long, is there anyway to use StringBuilders to make it a bit shorter and even use variables to pass in the `2M` and `5`?

Comment: Whenever you use `+`, you are _already_ using `StringBuilder`, but with cooler syntax.

Comment: Use a [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) or [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). Create a format `String` that is constant and set the variables.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think this is the case for Oracle's JVM but I don't think this is part of the JLS so that's not definite.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's actually down to the Java compiler you use (there is no bytecode for string concatenation, so it must be compiled into _some_ API calls). HotSpot may replace the whole thing with some even more efficient intrinsic.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, sorry, being stupid - I meant Oracle's compiler.

Comment: @orange what do you actually do after `updateJVMArguments` is called? Do you execute a Java command?

Answer (score 3):

Having a long string is a requirement of your application so there is little you can do about its length.
But you can improve its readability by splitting it across multiple lines :

```
    String.format("-Xloggc:gc_%s-%s.log " // This option that
            + "-verbose:gc " 
            + "-XX:+PrintGCDetails " // this activates such
            + "-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps "
            + "-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps "
            + "-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation "
            + "-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=%d "
            + "-XX:GCLogFileSize=%s", 
            myapp.getFileName(), getDateTime(), 5, "2M");
```

Not only is it readable at a simple glance as opposed to having to move a scroll bar. It leaves space for short comments about what each option is for.

Comment: It _will_ cause slowdown as a formatter is inherently slower than a `StringBuilder` - which is what the OP was using (implicitly). But it is much more readable so the minute slowdown should be disregarded. If you want it faster, you could use a `MessageFormat` which is preprocessed when constructed - a `String.format` call has to be evaluated every time it is used.

Comment: I was referring to the concatenation of strings, that does not cause a slowdown because the compiler optimizes them away. But I was not aware of the implications of using format regarding speed. In that case it might as well be better to plainly use concatenation for all of them and not use format at all.

Comment: On the first point - this is likely but not _guaranteed_ so don't rely on it. This is a suggestion in the JLS ([§15.18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)) not a requirement. On the second point I would strongly argue for readability over speed unless the code proves to be a bottleneck. I think your answer is sound and in fact the correct approach but you need to remove the part about not causing slowdown.

Comment: @Boris the Spider. I have to agree. I will still assume that my java compiler optimizes unless proven otherwise since that is the most likely case for production compilers. But it is good to be aware of the possibility of it not being optimized.

Answer (score 1):

This would be more readable if you use String.format:

```
String.format("-Xloggc:gc_%s-%s.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2M", myapp.getFileName(), getDateTime());
```

you can add additional place holders for the 2M and 5 values as well:

```
String.format("-Xloggc:gc_%s-%s.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=%s -XX:GCLogFileSize=%s", myapp.getFileName(), getDateTime(), 5, '2M');
```

Comment: You can make it even shorter: Remove the `-verbose:gc` as it is not used in combination with `-Xloggc:`. ;-)